# Java swing error with Java 8

Tags: java, swing

I have development one desktop application using java swing.
In Eclipse I have used jdk 1.6.

Now I have install this application in more computer, it works. On computer there are java 7 or java 6, but the application not have any problem.
Now I have install it in a pc with Java 7 and Java 8. So there are a strange symbol, in the component JMenu I have, for example this MenuIten "Visualizza DOcumenti", but I see "Vi_?  docu...nti"

If I try to unistall Java 8, the program works never problem.
I must have Java 8 on this PC, I can fixed it?

This is a sample code that I use for create a small menu:

```
            menu = new JMenu("Documenti");
            menuBar.add(menu);
            JMenu subMenuDDT = new JMenu("Genera DDT");
            menuItem = new JMenuItem("Visualizza DDT",KeyEvent.VK_T);
            menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                    KeyEvent.VK_M, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
            menuItem.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                    getContentPane().remove(0);
                    getContentPane().remove(toolBar);
                    PanelDDTVisualizza panelDDTV = new PanelDDTVisualizza();
                    panelDDTV.creaSwing();
                    toolBar = panelDDTV.inviaToolBar();  
                    getContentPane().add(panelDDTV, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    getContentPane().validate();
                }//fine metodoVoid
            });//fine actionlistener 
            subMenuDDT.add(menuItem);
```

I see strange character instead of signatures "Genera DDT", Documenti, Visualizza DDT

reguards

Comment: Can you show an example of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Maybe Java 7 uses UTF8 as default, but Java 8 not (e.g. using Windows-encoding as default). When Strings are loaded from custom resource files without specifying the encoding, such things might happen. I'm guessing that the question mark the OP mentions might be a unicode-unknown-codepoint symbol.

Comment: @cello - Close.  More likely it is the computers and the way that they have been set up ... and not a difference between Java 6/7 and Java 8.

Comment: I don't Know, because if I unistall Java 8, I don't have any problem